# How can i use selenium python to get a user's following on Ibstagram

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I use selnium python to get the list of people followed by a specific person?
I've been able to get to the list so far with:

```
    def getUserFollowing(self, username, maxima=None):
        self.browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + username)
        urlTEMP=username+'/following/'
        followingListButton = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,urlTEMP)]')
        followingListButton.click()
        actionChain = webdriver.ActionChains(self.browser)
        following = []
```

I don't know how i can make it load the list to the very end and how i can return it as a list.
Any and all help will be appreciated.
:>

Comment: What exactly do you want to be in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the functions I'm using for a while:

```
def get_users(no): #no = number of desired usernames
   n = no
   ac = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
   ac.key_down(Keys.SPACE).perform() #space button to load more users
   sleep(0.5)
   if len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('d7ByH')) < int(n):
       sleep(1)
       get_users(n)
   else:
       for item in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('d7ByH'): #class name for usernames
           vt_users.append(item.text) #your list name here
```

This function will expand the list until desired number of usernames are not loaded and then you can get all usernames(or whatever you want) in a list. Before calling this function click on the following button and add this also: `driver.find_element_by_class_name('isgrP').click()` for two times so that clicking on space scrolls the list successfully.

Hope you got what I want to tell.